# What philosophy of mathematics denies the existence of uncountable sets?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, infinity

Finitism denies the existence of infinite mathematical objects (e.g. quantification over infinite domains is not considered meaningful). Is the position that denies the existence of uncountable sets (but allows for countable, i.e. discrete, sets) defended in literature?

I searched for "discretism" without success.

Comment: I never heard about accepting countable sets but negating non-countable sets. Indeed I am sceptical that this is a useful position: Because the powerset of an infinite countable set is an uncountable set.

Comment: It's usually called predicativism, see [Storer(10)](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/items/4ca891dd-340a-4efe-9beb-17914106ea8d) for details (e.g. the denial of the powerset axiom).

Comment: @JoWehler Surely, if you hold such a position, you wouldn't accept the powerset axiom, I don't see a problem with that

Comment: @KristianBerry Thank you for the reference, I will take a look at it

Comment: @Victor Can you define the Cartesian product of two sets without using the power set axiom? - I am curious how much results used in mathematics can be saved in Storer's thesis. - Because you will look at the thesis: Could you afterwards add a short comment to your question?

Comment: @JoWehler You may indeed need the product axiom (i.e. assume that Set is a Cartesian category, but not a CCC). I am a bit busy at the moment, but I will be happy to add such a comment in the next few weeks.

Comment: There's a distinction to be made here between "classical finitism" and "strict finitism". [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Finitism#Classical_finitism_vs._strict_finitism): "Mary Tiles characterized those who allow potentially infinite objects as classical finitists, and those who do not allow potentially infinite objects as strict finitists: for example, a classical finitist would allow statements such as 'every natural number has a successor' and would accept the meaningfulness of infinite series in the sense of limits of finite partial sums, while a strict finitist would not."

Comment: A more common position is accepting the countable axiom of choice while rejecting the uncountable axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of subtle variations that the denial of a natural powerset (the powerset of ℕ) can take. In Barton and Friedman[[21](https://philarchive.org/archive/BARCAM-5)] we find that 2<sup>ℵ<sub>0</sub></sup> is inflated to the size of a proper class (c.f. Matthews[[21](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/29589/1/Thesis.pdf)] as well as ["pocket-sized set theory"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#PockSetTheo)), where proper classes might be taken to be in some sense "complete" infinities, but not as sets: they have elements but aren't themselves elements, e.g. for ORD (the proper class of ordinals) there is no {ORD}, etc. So there wouldn't be an {ℝ}, here.

On the other hand, one might deny the powerset of ℕ as a completed infinity altogether, too. This is more or less how it goes in predicativism, where a reference to "all" subsets of ℕ is taken to be impredicative. One can go even further and think through only the limit of predicativity "[given the natural numbers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/)":

> We also note that the addition of inaccessible set axioms to a weak subsystem of CZF (with no set induction) produces a theory of strength Γ<sub>0</sub>, the ordinal singled out by Feferman and Schütte as the limit of predicativity given the natural numbers (Crosilla and Rathjen 2001; see also section 1.3).

Then even Γ<sub>0</sub> becomes a sort of "barrier" within the domain of countable ordinals. That ordinal is, normally speaking, relatively small (or "short" might be a better description). What is this ordinal? [Here's a rather perspicuous expression from the MathSE, in terms of an infinite extension of the addition-multiplication-exponentiation-tetration sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131140/695171):

[image]

So regarding "predicativity given the natural numbers," we might speak of a denial not only of uncountable sets, but even of countable ones as of the above.

Note that, without the axiom scheme of replacement, one has only countably many uncountable alephs in play and ℵ<sub>ω</sub> is equivalent to the universe of sets. Also, [countable ordinals of length ω + ω and beyond are not provably sets in this context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155277/proof-that-we-cant-get-omega-omega-without-replacement). One will still have uncountable sets, but with serious restrictions on the details. How much this is compatible with the intuitions behind countabilism proper depends on whose intuitions we are speaking to.

**List of countabilist positions thus indicated:**

1. ℝ is a completed proper class, and is then not a set.
2. ℝ is neither complete nor incomplete as a  proper class, and is not a set.
3. ℝ is incomplete and is not a proper class, nor a set.
4. The same as (1), (2), or (3) except with Γ<sub>0</sub> in place of  ℝ.

Comment: I need to read up more on this notion of completeness, thanks for the references

Answer (score 1):

This position is called "countabilism." The 2022 paper "In defense of Countabilism" by Builes and Wilson is freely available on the Web (e.g. from Wilson's website, [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jmwilson/Builes-Wilson-In-Defense-of-Countabilism.pdf)). It cites many recent works on the subject and is a good entry-point into the literature.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Reading the paper, I don't know if its exactly what they are looking for. It's more of an argument for a new notion of size, rather than denying the existence of a countable set ( for the usual notion of cardinality)

Comment: @MichaelCarey I agree that the authors of the article seem to be arguing for some new notion of size. However, this is what the OP asked for:

"the position that denies the existence of uncountable sets (but allows for countable, i.e. discrete, sets) defended in literature". 

The paper I linked defines countabilism as follows: 

"Countabilism: Necessarily, every infinite collection (set or plurality) is countable." 

I think this indeed satisfies the description given by the OP, although perhaps it is also a bit stronger, due to the modal claim ("necessarily").

Comment: You are right, and It was a interesting read and a good answer, I guess my comment is just intended to add some clarification- that the paper's notion of "size" and so countability, is different than standard- so although they use the same word, it has a distinct meaning.